# How can I ban a specific socket from reconnecting to my chat?

Tags: sockets, server, chat

I'm writing a multi-client chat with managers and simple users. Whenever a manager kicks a user I don't want them to be able to just reconnect with the same username and IP address. How can I achieve something like that? I'm working in python, but I think a generic explanation of the idea might be better for more people to understand it.

Comment: Store the banned IP, and don't allow a reconnection if the users IP is banned?

Comment: But I might get more than a single connection from 1 external IP address. For example 2 people in the same house that use my chat. I only want to ban one of them, not both.

Comment: There's no way to do that reliably, see from the perspective of your server, their IP is really the only identifier you have for them. The only other alternative would be to force them to create an account that's verified by email; then you can ban their account and associated email instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You can store the ip in the banned ip database and then check if the the user is banned 
2) if you do not want to use database you can just create a cookie  when managers kicks the user and store at client side and check whether a client is banned or not.
 But solution 1 is more reliable